# Can anonymous types be used in text templates?

Tags: c#, t4, anonymous-types, implicit-typing

I am writing a [text template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126478.aspx) and have the following line of code:

```
Tuple<string, int, bool>[] tupleArray = new[]
    {
        new Tuple<string, int, bool>("apple", 4, true),
        new Tuple<string, int, bool>("grape", 1, false)
    };
```

I would like to convert this to an array of [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx):

```
var anonArray = new[]
    {
        new {Name = "apple", Diam = 4, Tasty = true},
        new {Name = "grape", Diam = 1, Tasty = false}
    };
```

The text template, however, though it appears to be a single contiguous function, does not allow the use of implicitly typed local variables.

Is there a simple way to bypass this limitation and use anonymous types within a text template?

Comment: This should work just fine, in Visual Studio 2010, I pasted your anonArray code directly into a template and then looped over the array with a foreach and all was well, as I'd expect.  What version of VS are you using?

Comment: @GarethJ Visual Studio 2010. And you're using a text template? A `.tt`?

Comment: Yep.  To be specific, I'm using 2010 SP1, but it shouldn't matter.

<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>
<#

var anonArray = new[] 
    { 
        new {Name = "apple", Diam = 4, Tasty = true}, 
        new {Name = "grape", Diam = 1, Tasty = false},
    }; 


#>

<# foreach ( var foo in anonArray)
   {
#>
Hello <#= foo.Name #> of type <#= foo.GetType() #>
<#
   }
#>

Comment: @GarethJ I don't get it. I swear `var` wasn't working before. I'll need to look into this a little harder..

Comment: We just expand the template with some boilerplate and then run the C# compiler over it via the CodeDOM, so in general, what works in C#, works in T4.  If you want to see what we're compiling, paste your template code into a runtime (preprocessed) template and you'll see the expansion.

Comment: Adding as an answer for future readers.

Answer (score 3):

```
Dictionary<string, int> set = 
  {
      { "apple", 4 },
      { "grape", 1 }
  }
```

That's probably about as concise as you can get.

EDIT: If you truly want the ability to use anonymous objects, you can always go with the bread and butter `dynamic` array:

```
dynamic[] array = new dynamic[] { new { Name = "Apple", Diam = 4 }, ... }
```

And then use late binding to access your properties. It's not like T4 templates have any intellisense anyways.

Comment: I'm looking for ways to use anonymous types. The code given was just an example of how I'm looking to clean up my own code, which has more attributes.

Comment: Are the anonymous objects created programmatically? If so, you could use LINQ to `Select` the elements into an IEnumerable

Comment: You should be looking to solve a problem, not to use some particular technical tool, unless your entire purpose here is to just learn about some particular technical tool.  If the latter is true, then this isn't an appropriate place to use anonymous classes, so you should find a better example to practice on.  This answer solves the  underlying problem.

Comment: @Servy What makes this an inappropriate place to use anonymous classes?

Comment: @Tejs The problem isn't creating the anonymous objects, it's storing them without the use of `var`.

Comment: `array[0].Name` - The property value is determined at run time with the `dynamic` type. Consider `dynamic` to act just like `object` in this instance, except that you can call out the properties / methods that dont necesarily exist.

Comment: This looks like what I want, but whenever I try and get an item from the array my template fails with `ErrorGeneratingOutput`. I can't even do a `foreach (var item in array) {}` loop.

Comment: You need to make sure the compiler is using `dynamic` - so use `foreach(dynamic item in array)`

Comment: This is an interesting discussion, but it doesn't address the question, to which the answer is 'yes, they do work'.

Answer (score 1):

This should work just fine.  In Visual Studio 2010, I pasted your anonArray code directly into a template and then looped over the array with a foreach and all was well, as I'd expect.  Here's the code as a template.

---

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>
<#
    var anonArray = new[] {
        new {Name = "apple", Diam = 4, Tasty = true},
        new {Name = "grape", Diam = 1, Tasty = false},
    };
#>
<# foreach ( var foo in anonArray) { #>
Hello <#= foo.Name #> of type <#= foo.GetType() #>
<# } #>
```

---

T4 just expands the template with some boilerplate and then runs the C# compiler over it via the CodeDOM, so in general, what works inside a method in C#, works in the body of a T4 template.  If you want to see what we're compiling, paste your template code into a runtime (preprocessed) template and you'll see the expansion as its output.